# Flask webserver run with waitress is not using before_request, only before_app_request

Tags: python, authentication, flask, web, waitress

I used to have this working:

auth.py

```
bp = Blueprint("auth", __name__)

@bp.before_app_request
def validate_token():
    # code
    session["user"] = user
```

index.py

```
@bp.route("/user")
def get_user():
    return make_response(session["user"], 200)
```

However, after implementing tests to the application, `before_app_request` was being called and since the testing agent is not authenticated (nor should they be), it'd break. Changing to `before_request` seemed to fix the problem. In fact, it works fine when I run it with `flask --app app_name run --debug`. However, I deploy it to production using waitress. Running `waitress-serve --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0 --call app_name:create_app`, the `before_request` is never called, resulting in an error.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: `before_request` is called before each request **within** the blueprint. To solve my error I had to keep the `before_app_request` and check if on the app config "testing" was `true`:

```
from flask import current_app as app

@bp.before_app_request
def validate_token():
    if app.testing:
        return
    #code
```

Not pretty but got the job done.